# Search for devices in range of bluetooth UWP

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, bluetooth, uwp

Is it possible to scan for devices in range of bluetooth? I tried FindAll method but it returns all paired devices. Also tried deviceWatcher with the same result.

Comment: https://32feet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hello, the problem is that methods return all paired devices both in range or not. I want to create a bluetooth scanner to find only devices in range.

Comment: Once a Bluetooth device has been paired with the system, the device is cached. After this, the device will be automatically discovered when querying. AFAIK, we can't get the paired device that is currently usable while enumerating devices.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to scan for devices in range of bluetooth?

This is possible, we can use either [DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync.aspx) method or [DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225446) class. But to get all Bluetooth devices, we need to note that **currently Bluetooth APIs don't provide a selector to get ALL devices that are both paired and non-paired**. [BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.getdeviceselector.aspx) method actually returns the same value as [BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.getdeviceselectorfrompairingstate.aspx). So when you use this selector (Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) string), you will always get all paired devices.

To get all devices, we can use this selector get paired devices first and then use `BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false)` to get the rest unpaired devices.

Or we can just specify the AQS string like following:

```
//The AQS string for getting all Bluetooth devices
var BluetoothDeviceSelector = "System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}\"";

//Using DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync method
var deviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDeviceSelector);

//Using DeviceWatcher class
var deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BluetoothDeviceSelector);
```

*PS: [FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync.aspx) method is more often used to look through the devices that are currently connected to or paired with the system. To get both paired and non-paired devices, it better to use [DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225446) class.*

For more info about how to use [FindAllAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync.aspx) method or [DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225446) class, please see [Enumerate devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices) and official [Device enumeration and pairing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing).

Besides [Bluetooth devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.aspx), there are also [Bluetooth LE devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.aspx) you might want to get. And for Bluetooth LE devices, the AQS string would be `System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:="{BB7BB05E-5972-42B5-94FC-76EAA7084D49}"`.

Comment: Jay, I am trying to do exactly like you are describing but keep having a problem - for a paired device, I cannot understand whether a device is actually available - System.Devices.Aep.IsPresent is returning true when initially scanning, and only turns false after a failed connection attempt. What do I do? Even the System.Devices.Aep.SignalStrength shows some cached value for the devices has not seen for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

`GetDeviceSelector` and friends return *strings* containing AQS queries. Have you ever looked at them?

### Paired

```
System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 
AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:="{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}" 
AND (
  System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True 
  OR System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.IssueInquiry:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False
)
```

### Unpaired

```
System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 
AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:="{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}" 
AND (
  System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False 
  OR System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.IssueInquiry:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
)
```

What do you think is tested by the expression in parentheses?

What do you think might happen if you omit this clause from the string you supply to `CreateWatcher`?

Something less obvious that you may find helpful is the fact that there are *two* Bluetooth protocol identifiers. The one shown above is for classic Bluetooth and the query does not match BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices.

The selector I suggest you use is

```
System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 
AND (
  System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:="{BB7BB05E-5972-42B5-94FC-76EAA7084D49}" 
  OR System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:="{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}#"
)
```

I have put line breaks in all these queries to help you read them. Don't include them in your code. For convenience here's some code from one of my projects.

```
string BleSelector = "System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND (System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{BB7BB05E-5972-42B5-94FC-76EAA7084D49}\" OR System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{E0CBF06C-CD8B-4647-BB8A-263B43F0F974}\")";
string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected", "System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId" };
deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BleSelector, requestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
```

Using a watcher has the advantage that the list becomes available progressively. `FindAllAsync` may be asynchronous but it takes ages to return.

Comment: Can you explain what the Aep.Bluetooth.IssueInquiry parameter means for the query?  I note that in the "standard" selectors it consistently has the opposite boolean value of Aep.IsPaired, whether looking for paired or unpaired devices.  What would it mean if they had the same boolean value?  I note that your BleSelector simply omits both of those parameters, which was my inclination (before discovering your post) to log all devices whether paired or unpaired.  In fact, I composed exactly the same query.  (I'm still probing and learning this stuff.)  Thanks.

Comment: I think I just found a partial answer to my own question: "The AQS Filter string will request scanning to be performed when the pairingState is false" and presumably not request scanning when the pairing state is true.  But, if I don't specify IsPaired or IssueInquiry at all, does it issue an inquiry, or not?  Based on the time that it takes to return, I sense that it does issue an inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

I provide BluetoothLE Device Selector string in the following code. It works for me.

```
 DeviceWatcher dWatcher = null;
 var BluetoothDeviceSelector = "System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{BB7BB05E-5972-42B5-94FC-76EAA7084D49}\" AND ((System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True OR System.Devices.Aep.IsPaired:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False) OR System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.IssueInquiry:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#False)";

 dWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(BluetoothDeviceSelector);

 dWatcher.Added += DeviceAdded;
 dWatcher.Updated += DeviceUpdated;

 dWatcher.Start();
```